# Google Cloud SDK SSL Certification Verify Failed on installation

Tags: ssl, sdk, google-cloud-platform, failed-installation

I am trying to install Cloud SDK on windows 8 running Python 2.7.14 but when running the install.bat file it gives: SSL Certification Failed as shown in the attached snapshots. Any help?

[image: Installation fail]
[image: System variables]

Comment: Please don't post text as images - unsearchable.

Comment: Did you end up fixing this? Having the same issue.